# Divide country in regions QGIS

Tags: qgis, region, gadm, brazil

I'm developing a project on Brazil and I need to devide the country into 4 regions (N,NE,S,SE). I've downloaded the GADM data and opened them in QGIS, so now I have the situation in the image.
How can I divide the country into the 4 regions? Which are the steps and how to do that?
My output should be a csv file with latitude/longitude.
P.S. I'm new to QGIS[image]

Comment: Select corresponding features and export them to different geopackages.

Comment: @Erik As the output need to be a csv why exporting to gpkg rather than csv…

Comment: Do you want the regions to have borders following the existing borders between political regions or do you just want to split with two straight lines? It is also a bit unclear for me what you want in the csv file as a csv file is a good match for points, but from your split - either if it is along existing border or not - will give you polygons.

Comment: @MortenSickel I want the 4 regions indicated in the field I need to analyse (So North, North East, South, South East). Ok maybe you're right, I need polygons, I'm really confused right now because I'm new to Qgis.
In a few words, I have an excel file with several (more that 2000) power plants and I have to filter them in the 4 regions of Brazil. For each plan I have latitude and longitude.
So what I have to do is to split through Qgis the Brazil in 4 regions in order to then classify my power plant file (I still don't understand how to do that, but this will be a further problem).

Comment: @Erik sorry could you be more clear? I mean with the exact passages I need to do. I opened Qgis this morning for the first time.

Comment: I suggest you get familiar with the [official QGIS training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/index.html). All basic tasks are covered there, and a lot of useful information.